# CSS - float: right moves element down, does not come in same level

Tags: html, css, django

I have created a container and three divs inside that.

The first two divs are inside a for loop, the data is coming from backend (django) and the number of divs is created accordingly.

The right div is a place where I want to place some elements, which should be at same level but it's coming at the very bottom of the container div.

HTML :

```
<form method="POST" action="runrobo" name="runrobomain">
    <div id="container_runrobo">
        <div id="runrobo_left"><b>Test Suite Name</b></div>
        <div id="runrobo_center"><b>Order (Priority)</b></div>
        {% for suite_name in data %}
        <div id="runrobo_left">
            <input type="checkbox" name="suite_checkbox" value="{{ suite_name }}">&nbsp;{{suite_name}}
        </div>
        <div id="runrobo_center">
            <input type="text" name="suite_order">
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
        <div id="runrobo_right">
            <b>More Config Options</b>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

CSS :

```
#container_runrobo {
    width: 90%;
    margin-left: 1%;
    background-color: lightgray;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#runrobo_left {
  float: left;
  width: 30%;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#runrobo_center {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 30%;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#runrobo_right {
  float: right;
  width: 30%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Now, after googling a lot, I added another div after the right one :

```
<div style="clear: both;>&nbsp;</div>
```

But that too did not solve my problem.

Comment: You need to understand how `float` works.

Comment: Looks like the *step-down effect* - have you considered placing `#runrobo_right` *after* `#runrobo_left` and *before* `#runrobo_center`?

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError There is only 1 right div and multiple left, center divs. As the left and center divs are inside a for loop, and I don't want to create that many right divs.

Comment: I'm not suggesting you should (create more "right divs"), but rather advising an *alternative placement* of the element in question (`#runrobo_right`). Have you tried placing this element *first*, **before** any other elements?

Comment: Nope, haven't. Will do so.

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError it worked ! Thanks.

Comment: Happy to hear it :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161180/discussion-between-ayush-and-uncaughttypeerror).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @UncaughtTypeError in comments, placing the #runrobo_right div before other two divs solved the problem.

So the HTML would look like :

```
<form method="POST" action="runrobo" name="runrobomain">
    <div id="container_runrobo">
        <div id="runrobo_right">
            <b>More Config Options</b>
        </div>
        <div id="runrobo_left"><b>Test Suite Name</b></div>
        <div id="runrobo_center"><b>Order (Priority)</b></div>
        {% for suite_name in data %}
        <div id="runrobo_left">
            <input type="checkbox" name="suite_checkbox" value="{{ suite_name }}">&nbsp;{{suite_name}}
        </div>
        <div id="runrobo_center">
            <input type="text" name="suite_order">
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</form>
```